# Does an ASP.NET SQL Library Exist for Managing Tables?

Tags: sql, .net

Does anyone know of a `SQL` library in `ASP.NET` that can be used to manage tables?

E.g.

```
SQLTable table = new SQLTable();
table.AddColumn(“First name”, varchar, 100);
table.AddColumn(“Last name”, varchar, 100);
if(table.ColumnExists(“Company”))
  table.RemoveColumn(“Company”);
```

The operations I am looking for are adding, editing and deleting tables, fields, indexes and foreign keys.

This can be done using `SQL` but it is messy, I am looking for a clean API that is intuitive to use.

Comment: Just to nitpick, but shouldn't the first line be: SQLTable table = new SQLTable(); ?

Comment: Also: I wouldn't expect it to remove a column you've haven't added, unless you've done something to connect it to an existing table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo

Other option would be to install the Microsoft Sql Server Web Data Administrator

[Sql Server Web Data Administrator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=C039A798-C57A-419E-ACBC-2A332CB7F959&displaylang=en)

Some references for Smo:

[Create Table in SQL Server 2005 Using C# and SMO](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/01/27/2775.aspx)

[How to: Create, Alter, and Remove a Table in Visual Basic .NET (sorry for lang choice)](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms162203.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[Subsonic](http://subsonicproject.com/) has a [migrations](http://subsonicproject.com/2-1-pakala/subsonic-using-migrations/) feature. It's fairly new, but I think it meets your  'intuitive' requirement.

Comment: Subsonic will also build scaffolds for you. That's another nice thing that I like about it.

Answer (score 0):

I would tell you to use SQL DMO, but it looks like it's being discontinued by the looks of it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131540.aspx

Not sure what it's being replaced with.